# How can I increase clipboard size in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, clipboard

I am using ubuntu 12.04 and apache2 server. I have a lot of text and images to be copied from my application to a spreadsheet. There is some sort of limit in Ubuntu clipboard because of which I cannot copy all of the data.

How can increase clipboard size in Ubuntu?

Comment: there is no clipboard size limitation. the only notable limitation of the clipboard is that sometime pasting does not work after the source has been closed ( https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/11334 ).

Comment: what are you doing exactly?

Comment: I have an apache server in windows and ubuntu. I am exporting data to spreadsheet by copying to clipboard.its working fine in windows but not in Ubuntu. Only 1700 cels are getting copied in Ubuntu.

Comment: apache has nothing to do with this. amongst others, the browser you copy from, the spreadsheet app you paste to, and possibly a clipboard manager you have installed might break it.